# NumberFormatException getting simplecart items,quantity,price and grandtotal in an array in java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, numberformatexception, simplecart

I have implemented simplecart to my project.

On clicking the checkout button it went to PayPal which I didn't wanted it to. So I changed the action URL in simplecart.js file to point to my servlet

```
action = opts.sandbox ? "cart_checkout" :"cart_checkout",
                        method = opts.method === "GET" ? "GET" : "POST";
```

It calls the servlet but I get a NumberFormatException in my servlet

Servlet

```
package com.kunal.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CartCheckout
 */
@WebServlet("/CartCheckout")
public class CartCheckout extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CartCheckout() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String count=request.getParameter("ItemCount");
        ArrayList<String> item_detail=new ArrayList<String>();
        int cnt=Integer.parseInt(count);
        for(int i=1;i<cnt+1;i++)
        {
            String name=request.getParameter("item_name_");
            item_detail.add(name);
            String price=request.getParameter("item_price_");
            item_detail.add(price);
            String qty=request.getParameter("item_quantity_");
            item_detail.add(qty);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String count=request.getParameter("ItemCount");
        ArrayList<String> item_detail=new ArrayList<String>();
        int cnt=Integer.parseInt(count);
        for(int i=1;i<cnt+1;i++)
        {
            String name=request.getParameter("item_name_");
            item_detail.add(name);
            String price=request.getParameter("item_price_");
            item_detail.add(price);
            String qty=request.getParameter("item_quantity_");
            item_detail.add(qty);
        }
    }

}
```

Stacktrace

```
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Agro' did not find a matching property.
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 763 ms
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1316 ms
Sep 01, 2014 1:15:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Cart_Checkout] in context with path [/Agro] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.kunal.servlet.CartCheckout.doPost(CartCheckout.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should capture the request that is being sent to your webservice.

In the error you can see that you get a `NumberFormatException: null`. This suggests that your `count` String is `null`.

```
String count=request.getParameter("ItemCount");
```

This can happen when ItemCount is not a parameter of your request.

It would be good practice to test `count` (= "ItemCount" parameter) for null values in your code, so that you can return a nice looking error to your client.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your count variable is null you can avoid it by

```
String count=request.getParameter("ItemCount");
if(count.length()>0){
   int cnt=Integer.parseInt(count.trim());
   // other logic
}
 else{
       //do nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is quite straightforward:

```
int cnt=Integer.parseInt(count);
```

this is pointed out clearly from your stack trace:

```
at com.kunal.servlet.CartCheckout.doPost(CartCheckout.java:53)
```

A simple solution would be to check the count against **null**, hence change your `doPost (..)` implementation into:

```
    /**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String count=request.getParameter("ItemCount");
    ArrayList<String> item_detail=new ArrayList<String>();
    int cnt= count == null 0 : Integer.parseInt(count);
    for(int i=1;i<cnt+1;i++)
    {
        String name=request.getParameter("item_name_");
        item_detail.add(name);
        String price=request.getParameter("item_price_");
        item_detail.add(price);
        String qty=request.getParameter("item_quantity_");
        item_detail.add(qty);
    }
}
```

In order to ensure that you'll not encounter the same issue with empty strings, you can check also for empty strings. If using other libraries is an option I would suggest using [StringUtils.isNotBlank(..)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank(java.lang.String))

then your parsing line becomes:

```
int cnt= StringUtils.isNotBlank(count) 0 : Integer.parseInt(count);
```